# Duplicate section of PHP Form with different name identifiers

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I've created a PHP form that looks like this, to add details about faculty members.
[image]

I want to be able to duplicate this section (inside the borders) with different IDs. Can I store each member's details in an array?

This is what it should look like after adding another member.
[image]

My code is below:

```
<html>
    <style>
    .container { width:21%; border:1px solid #d3d3d3; }
    .container div { width:99%; }
    .container .header { background-color:#d3d3d3; padding: 2px; cursor: pointer; font-weight: bold; }
    .container .content { display: none; padding : 5px; }
    .faculty {border: 1px black solid;}
    </style>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <script src="jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="added.php" method="post">
            <div class="container"><div class="header">Faculty</div>
                <div class="content">
                    <input type="button" id="f_add" value="Add Member" /> <input type="button" id="f_rem" value="Remove Last" />
                    <div class="faculty" name="f_1" id="f_1">
                        Name: <input type="text" name="f_name_1" required /><br>
                        Role:&nbsp;&nbsp; <input type="text" name="f_role_1" required /><br>
                        Email: <input type="text" name="f_email_1" /> <br>
                        Biography: <textarea name="f_bio_1" rows="5" cols="38"></textarea><br>
                        Office Hours:<br><input type="checkbox" name="f_mon_0" /> Mon <input type="checkbox" name="f_tue_0" /> Tue <input type="checkbox" name="f_wed_0" /> Wed <input type="checkbox" name="f_thu_0" /> Thu <input type="checkbox" name="f_fri_0" /> Fri <br>
                        Image: <input type="file" name="f_image_0" /><br>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
            <script>
                $(".header").click(function () {
                    $(this).next().slideToggle(500, function () {});
                });
                $("#f_add").click(function () {
                    $(".faculty").clone().prop({name: "f2", id: "f2"}).appendTo(".content");
                });
                $("#f_rem").click(function () {

                });
            </script>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, you can store all of the details in an array.

Comment: Can you give me an example of how?

Comment: can use array names on form controls

Answer (score 0):

You can user name array instead of

user array format 
Session1
    
Session2

So in your $_POST instead of get the values by
    $_POST[f_name_1]

use
    $session1_fname = $_POST[Session1][f_name]
    $session2_fname = $_POST[Session2][f_name]